# On Mutually Exclusivity of Two Questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Would the question,

> What are the criteria of being a good parent?

And

> What are the criteria of being a poor parent?

have answers that are mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 5):

I think the answers might be different, but I have to say that I don't feel "What are the criteria of being a poor parent?" is a constructive question.

If they are seen as distinct questions, then the only purpose I could see for the "poor parent" question would be for ways to label or judge parents negatively.  This isn't constructive, whereas the "good parent" version can be construed as a means of setting goals.

Comment: I suspect I'd vote to close either way of wording. Too subjective, too local.